# Он Сергей(,) и я Сергей

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

***У нас с отцом одинаковые имена: он Сергей и я Сергей.*** *(Алексин А."А тем временем где-то"*)

Как объяснить отсутствие запятой перед союзом И? Однородностью конструкций после двоеточия?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1)У нас с отцом одинаковые имена: (2) он Сергей и (3) я Сергей.

**Из Правил Лопатина:**

Запятая не ставится,  если части сложносочиненного предложения имеют ....общую, поясняемую ими, часть сложного предложения: Останавливаться было нельзя: ноги засасывало и следы наливались водой (Пауст.).

Comment: Две соединенных союзом "и" части сложной конструкции могут иметь общую объединяющую их третью часть. Она включает в себя смысл обоих частей и соединена с ними бессоюзной связью: "Это было похоже на чудо: за занавесом оказалась сцена и на ней в вальсе кружились маленькие балеринки", - рассказывала Машенька о балете "Щелкунчик", который посмотрела в Новый Год.http://www.portal-slovo.ru/philology/37435.php

Answer (score 0):

> Однородностью конструкций после двоеточия?

Ну да, в общем-то это  вполне можно назвать "однородностью", не противоречит общей логике. Она проявляется как ряд поле обобщающей конструкции. Суть именно такова.

Но в общепринятой формулировке правила этот термин не употребляется, чтобы не запутать окончательно. Говорят  просто об общей части двух составляющих. Остальное - см. у Sibylla.